# Image Map tag doesn't work in Google Chrome with Joomla 2.5?

Tags: html, joomla, joomla2.5

Can any one tell me where the error is in this html coding?

```
<object style="max-width: 100%;" data="images/solution_new.jpg" width="575" height="500" usemap="#Map" border="0"> </object> 
<map id="Map" name="Map"> 
<area shape="rect" alt="" coords="40,395,143,492" href="associates" />
<area shape="rect" coords="12,18,211,110" href="solutions/business-ob" />
<area shape="rect" alt="" coords="419,26,568,135" href="associates" />
<area shape="rect" coords="390,373,522,483" href="solutions/consumer-oc" />
</map>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: are you being shown any errors in chrome dev tools?

Comment: How and where you are adding the code ? In an article using editor? If yes, your editor won't allow you to add it unless you are a super user

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me as if it hasn't been implemented in Chrome

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#attr-hyperlink-usemap

According to HTML spec usemap is allowed in an **object** tag and should be treated in the same way like for **img** tag

You may want to use img instead of object

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when using `<object>` and `<map>` and Chrome 26. Changing `<object>` to `<img>` solved the problem.